# What is AwesomePlayer?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-3, media-player

In looking in my logs I see `AwesomePlayer` running. I am currently not playing any media, so I'm wondering what it is, and why it's running. My device is a Samsung Galaxy S3.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[AwesomePlayer](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/av/+/master/media/libstagefright/) is the built-in media player, part of Android's media playback engine.  It's also referred to as the [Stagefright player](http://quandarypeak.com/2013/08/androids-stagefright-media-player-architecture/).

You may be seeing the player's entries in the log while not playing any music or videos, because it handles *all* media playback, including ringtones and notification sounds.

Comment: Thank you for answering the what - how about the why? Any idea why it would be running and creating so many logs when I'm not playing any media and no apps are running in the background.

Comment: It handle all media, including ringtones and notification sounds.

Comment: Yup, AwesomePlayer handles literally all media.